# UTF-8 properties files in JavaEE

Tags: jakarta-ee, utf-8, intellij-idea, ascii, properties-file

I have a .properties file with ru_RU localization for my web project.
The words taken from this file by ResourceBoundle are displayed on jsp as "???"

I use Intellij IDEA 14 with tomcat8 on Linux, with option "Transparent native-to-ascii conversation", so file with russian symbols looks like key = "\uXXXX\uXXXX\uXXXX"

I think It's can be a problem with russian font. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

I foolishly forgotten about pageEncoding in page tag:
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
so if pageEncoding not specified browser detects ISO-8859-1 as default encoding and shows ??? instead of cyrillic symbols.

SOLVED.

Answer (score 0):

.properties files have to be ISO-8859-1, no exceptions. What you see in the file is normal and correct, provided of course that those are `\u04XX` (the Unicode block for Cyrillic).

If the browser shows ?'s, it's another problem elsewhere. You may need make sure everything on the rendering side is using UTF-8. AFAIK, by default JavaEE uses ISO-8859-1, so you need to switch it explicitly to UTF-8.